# Angular 4 : Master page with side bar concept

Tags: html, css, angular, master-pages

I'm working with Angular 4 and I wanted to create a master page concept for all pages.

This is what I want :

[image]

In fact, I want to have a authentication page with its own template (like my screen), and others pages, with a different template.

For example, I want to have a **fixed toolbar and a left sidebar**. And inside page, a **dynamic content**.

In my idea, the router-outlet in the page AppComponent will display Authentication page or "Master Page" (toolbar and sidebar) and then, in this Master Page, I created a Div for my **dynamic** content.

But it doesn't work...

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular4, then use [components](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html).

You can make theses components:

```
Authentification
Authentification-Content
Authentification-Sidebar
Master
Master-Titlebar
Master-Sidebar
Master-Content
Home
Product
```

Then it's just a matter of injecting components into each other to get the desired results.

For example, if you wanted to show the Product page, you'd have your component injected like this:

```
index.html
    Master
        Master-Titlebar
        Master-Sidebar
        Master-content
            Product
```